# Marshalling JavaBeans to several formats

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, javabeans

I've got simple JavaBeans objects which represents data in my database. I want to transform this to several formats(XML, JSON) to share it to my clients and I also need reverse transformation. What tools do you advise to me to do this? I need fast, simple and not complicated tool. I know GSON or JSONObject will be nice for JSON producing but what about XML? I found JAXB is too "fat" for my needs. Or maybe I'm wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**MOXy** offers both XML and JSON binding by leveraging the JAXB metadata plus it's own extensions.  In the example below the same object with the same metadata is mapped to both the XML and JSON representations of the [Google Maps Geocoding API V2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html

**MOXy** also has an external mapping document that allows you to map a single object model to multiple XML or JSON representations.  In the next example one object model is mapped to the results of both the Google and Yahoo weather APIs:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

One of the things that make **MOXy** so flexible is its path based mapping which breaks the one-to-one relationship between objects and nodes in XML and JSON messages:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Plus since [**EclipseLink as offers a JPA implementation**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php), **MOXy** contains extensions for handling objects that are also mapped to the database:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll keep it in mind and will read MOXy docs.